# ACL verification fails for Data Factory Service Principal, although it has rwx permissions

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql, azure-data-factory

I have a U-SQL script that executes successfully from VS Code with my personal credentials, but fails when triggered from a Data Factory pipeline. My personal account has Owner rights on the Azure subscription. ADF uses Service Principal authentication with Data Lake Analytics & Store.

I am using Data Factory V2 and Data Lake Gen1 with the Default Integration Runtime. ADLA Firewall is disabled.

The U-SQL script is very simple, it just reads data from a CSV file and tries to write it in another CSV file. This is the whole script:

```
@companies = 
    EXTRACT
        Id string,
        Name string
    FROM @InputFile
    USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows: 1);

OUTPUT @companies
    TO @OutputFile
    USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader: true);
```

The parameters *InputFile* and *OutputFile* contain the ADL paths to the input and output data. These parameters are passed from Data Factory. The first stage of the script ("Extract") executes successfully, and the graph shows that the error occurs in the "PodAggregate" stage. A similar error occurs if I try to write the output to a managed table instead of a CSV file.

The high level error message in Data Factory is:

> Error Id: VertexFailedFast, Error Message: Vertex failed with a fail-fast error.

Data Lake Analytics gives the more detailed error:

> E_STORE_USER_ERROR: A user error has been reported when reading or writing data.
>
> Component: STORE
>
> Description: Operation 'Open::Wait' returned error code -2096559454 'Forbidden. ACL verification failed. Either the resource does not exist or the user is not authorized to perform the requested operation.' for stream 'adl://[myadl].azuredatalakestore.net/adla/tmp/8a1495dc-8d80-44b9-a724-f2a0a963b3c8/stack_test/Companies.csv---6F21F973-45B9-46C7-805F-192672C99393-9_0_1.dtf%23N'.
>
> Details:
>
> Stream name 'adl://[myadl].azuredatalakestore.net/adla/tmp/8a1495dc-8d80-44b9-a724-f2a0a963b3c8/stack_test/Companies.csv---6F21F973-45B9-46C7-805F-192672C99393-9_0_1.dtf%23N'
>
> Thu Jul 19 02:35:42 2018: Store user error, Operation:[Open::Wait], ErrorEither the resource does not exist or the current user is not authorized to perform the requested operation
>       7ffd8c4195b7  ScopeEngine!?ToStringInternal@KeySampleCollection@SSLibV3@ScopeEngine@@AEAA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ + 11b7
>       7ffd8c39a96d  ScopeEngine!??0ExceptionWithStack@ScopeEngine@@QEAA@W4ErrorNumber@1@AEBV?$initializer_list@VScopeErrorArg@ScopeCommon@@@std@@_N@Z + 13d 
>       7ffd8c3abe3e  ScopeEngine!??0DeviceException@ScopeEngine@@QEAA@AEAVBlockDevice@1@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@J@Z + 1de
>       7ffd8c3f8c7b  ScopeEngine!?GetTotalIoWaitTime@Statistics@Scanner@ScopeEngine@@QEAA_JXZ + 133b 
>       7ffd8c3f87dc  ScopeEngine!?GetTotalIoWaitTime@Statistics@Scanner@ScopeEngine@@QEAA_JXZ + e9c
>       7ffd9157780d  **ScopeCodeGenEngine**!ScopeEngine::CosmosOutput::IssueWritePage + 4d   d:\data\yarnnm\local\usercache\f675bad0-3d48-4f08-9933-d7cb614ec7a8\appcache\application_1531519980045_88416\container_e194_1531519980045_88416_01_000001\wd\scopeio.h line:6063
>       7ffd9156be7d  **ScopeCodeGenEngine**!ScopeEngine::TextOutputStream,ScopeEngine::CosmosOutput>::Write + 2bd d:\data\yarnnm\local\usercache\f675bad0-3d48-4f08-9933-d7cb614ec7a8\appcache\application_1531519980045_88416\container_e194_1531519980045_88416_01_000001\wd\scopeio.h line:7828
>       7ffd91579290  **ScopeCodeGenEngine**!ScopeEngine::TextOutputPolicy::SerializeHeader + 30  d:\data\yarnnm\local\usercache\f675bad0-3d48-4f08-9933-d7cb614ec7a8\appcache\application_1531519980045_88416\container_e194_1531519980045_88416_01_000001\wd__scopecodegenengine__.dll.cpp line:514
>       7ffd91574ba7  **ScopeCodeGenEngine**!ScopeEngine::Outputer,ScopeEngine::BinaryInputStream,ScopeEngine::ExecutionStats>,SV1_Extract_out0,ScopeEngine::ScopeUnionAll,ScopeEngine::BinaryInputStream,ScopeEngine::ExecutionStats>,SV1_Extract_out0>,3>,SV1_Extract_out0,1>,SV1_Extract_out0,ScopeEngine::TextOutputPolicy,ScopeEngine::TextOutputStream,ScopeEngine::CosmosOutput>,0,ScopeEngine::ExecutionStats,ScopeEngine::DummyStatsWriter>::DoOutput + 27    d:\data\yarnnm\local\usercache\f675bad0-3d48-4f08-9933-d7cb614ec7a8\appcache\application_1531519980045_88416\container_e194_1531519980045_88416_01_000001\wd\scopeoperators.h line:5713
>       7ffd91582258  **ScopeCodeGenEngine**!SV2_PodAggregate_execute + 658   d:\data\yarnnm\local\usercache\f675bad0-3d48-4f08-9933-d7cb614ec7a8\appcache\application_1531519980045_88416\container_e194_1531519980045_88416_01_000001\wd__scopecodegenengine__.dll.cpp line:722
>       7ffd8c36571d  ScopeEngine!??1OutputFileInfo@ScopeEngine@@QEAA@XZ + 60d
>       7ffd8c397aa0  ScopeEngine!?RunUserCode@Vertex@ScopeEngine@@SA_N_NAEBV?$function@$$A6AXXZ@std@@@Z + 1b0
>       7ffd8c397a4e  ScopeEngine!?RunUserCode@Vertex@ScopeEngine@@SA_N_NAEBV?$function@$$A6AXXZ@std@@@Z + 15e
>       7ffd8c397915  ScopeEngine!?RunUserCode@Vertex@ScopeEngine@@SA_N_NAEBV?$function@$$A6AXXZ@std@@@Z + 25 
>       7ffd8c365c7f  ScopeEngine!??1OutputFileInfo@ScopeEngine@@QEAA@XZ + b6f
>       7ffd8c3950c4  ScopeEngine!?Execute@Vertex@ScopeEngine@@SA_NAEBVVertexStartupInfo@2@PEAUVertexExecutionInfo@2@@Z + 3f4 
>       7ff731d8ae8d  scopehost!(no name) 
>       7ff731d8adbd  scopehost!(no name) 
>       7ffd8c4274d9  ScopeEngine!?Execute@VertexHostBase@ScopeEngine@@IEAA_NAEAVVertexStartupInfo@2@@Z + 379 
>       7ff731d8d236  scopehost!(no name) 
>       7ff731d6a966  scopehost!(no name) 
>       7ff731d98dac  scopehost!(no name) 
>       7ffd9e4713d2  KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk + 22
>       7ffd9e5e54e4  ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart + 34

The Service Principal account has **Owner** permissions on Data Lake Analytics. The SP account also has (default) **rwx** permissions on the /stack_test subdirectory in Data Lake Store and all its files and children, and **x** permission on the root directory. The error message seems to say that the SP account is missing permissions on the destination file (/stack_test/Companies.csv), but I can explicitly see that it has **rwx** on that file. Which permissions am I still missing?

For reference, the script and the Data Factory resources necessary to reproduce this problem can be found at: https://github.com/lehmus/StackQuestions/tree/master/ADF_ADLA_Auth.

Comment: I can confirm that we have an Data Lake Analytics instance that started throwing the same errors yesterday. It does work if the job is published and executed with a personal account, but the service principle appears to perhaps have lost permissions to the tmp folder? If you get the same error, perhaps there was a service upgrade yesterday? It started between 11:47 (worked) and 12:45 (failed) UTC times.

Comment: Yes, this issue seems to be related to the tmp folder. Apparently the U-SQL jobs have started to use /adla/tmp as their temporary storage. Since my ADF user has only x (default) permission on the root, it does not have write permission on the temporary folder. I can create this folder manually and grant write access to tmp to run the job successfully once. A more permanent fix would be to grant default write access to the root, but this is not a good practice.

Comment: @SondreB, did you create a support ticket?

Comment: @FangLiu We have created a ticket with MS. Seems the change in how ADLA employs tmp folders is unannounced. As a work around, we have temporarily granted write access on root, but are awaiting a better solution from MS.

Comment: @larsts What is the status of your ticket, has this issue been addressed?

Comment: @Lazer The issue has been addressed and the ticket closed. ASFAIK the version introducing the error situation was rolled back by Microsoft (although they were never able to supply a date for when this was rolled back/rectified). We have in any case reverted our work around, having W on root, and everything is running smoothly.